# how to filter collection docs based on another collection?

Tags: mongodb, express

I want to create a controller for my mongo collection of `cases` and `users`.
I want to filter the `cases` that have a `userName` prop that does not associate with a `user` in the  `Users` collection.  I want to `res`pond to the client with the caseDocs that have problematic usersNames.

Below is what I've been banging my head with:

```js
const noUserFuncController = async (res, res) => {
  const cases = await CaseFile.find({})
  const noUsersarr = []
   cases.forEach(async caseDoc => {
    const usr = await Users.findOne({ userName: caseDoc.user })
    if (!usr) {
      noUsers.push(caseDoc)
    }
  })
  res.json(noUsersarr)
}
```

Any input is appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: {
   $lookup:
     {
       from: `Cases`,
       localField: `user`,
       foreignField: `userName`,
       as: *what goes here*?
     }
}

(sorry i dont know how to better format here)
How do I make sure to return cases that dont have a username?

Comment: this only returns userNames.   i want to return cases that have a `userName` which is not equal to any `user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a aggregation query with `$lookup` stage to join user information, and `$match` stage to match if user response if empty [],

```
const noUserFuncController = async (res, res) => {

  const noUsersarr = await CaseFile.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users", // confirm your collection name here
        localField: "user",
        foreignField: "userName",
        as: "user"
      }
    },
    { $match: { user: [] } }
  ]);

  res.json(noUsersarr);

}
```